# Image Saving from Google Colab to google drive

Tags: image, google-colaboratory

Image file saving problem in **from google colaboratory to google drive**. Solution for file downloading is available but for saving file in drive from google colab isn't seen too much.

Answer (score 2):

I was dealing with image files and looking for saving processed image in google drive instead of downloading them google drive. And the solution command `img.save("/content/drive/MyDrive/aa/xyz.jpeg")` of PTL library works like magic.
Below the overall code snippet.

```
from PIL import Image
import os
from pathlib import Path


path = r"/content/drive/MyDrive/aa/train"
os.chdir(path)

file_path = f"/content/drive/MyDrive/aa/train/xyz.jpeg"  # Image file path

## image cropping and saving 

img = Image.open(file_path)
img = img.resize((250,250), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save("/content/drive/MyDrive/aa/xyz.jpeg") # Image saving to another directory
```

So you can easily read image from google drive and save image to google drive from google colab.